# Synchronous vs Asynchronous Salesforce

Tags: soql

What is Synchronous and Asynchronous execution in Salesforce? Can anyone explain? I saw in governor limits

> Total  Soql Queries in Synchronous is 100 and in Asynchronous is 200

What is Synchronous and Asynchronous here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronous is code that is run "on demand", and includes Visualforce and Lightning controllers, triggers, and code called by @RemoteAction, webservice, @RestResource, etc. Asynchronous code is code that runs "when available", which is implemented by one of the asynchronous calls: Schedulable, Queueable, Batchable, and @future methods.

Comment: Platform events are asynchronous...but which limits bucket do they fit into?

Comment: @AdrianLarson The triggers themselves are synchronous (using the more restrictive synchronous governor limits).